# How to store the values of a slider in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created 5 sliders which changes their values as we slide them. Now I want to store the values of these sliders in a variable so that I can do some calculations like add the total values of all sliders and print them.

Here is my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Slider functionality</title>
      <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script>
         $(function() {

            $( "#slider-1" ).slider({
               range:true,
               min: 0,
               max: 500,
               values: [ 0, 0],
               slide: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( "#priceA" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
               }
           });
         $( "#priceA" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-1" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " - $" + $( "#slider-1" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

            $( "#slider-2" ).slider({
               range:true,
               min: 0,
               max: 500,
               values: [ 0, 0],
               slide: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( "#priceB" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
               }
           });
         $( "#priceB" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-2" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " - $" + $( "#slider-2" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

            $( "#slider-3" ).slider({
               range:true,
               min: 0,
               max: 500,
               values: [ 0, 0],
               slide: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( "#priceC" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
               }
           });
         $( "#priceC" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-3" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " - $" + $( "#slider-3" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

            $( "#slider-4" ).slider({
               range:true,
               min: 0,
               max: 500,
               values: [ 0, 0],
               slide: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( "#priceD" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
               }
           });
         $( "#priceD" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-4" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " - $" + $( "#slider-4" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

            $( "#slider-5" ).slider({
               range:true,
               min: 0,
               max: 500,
               values: [ 0, 0],
               slide: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( "#priceE" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
               }
           });
         $( "#priceE" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-5" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " - $" + $( "#slider-5" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- HTML --> 
      <p>
         <label for="priceA">Price rangeA:</label>
         <input type="text" id="priceA" 
            style="border:0; color:#b9cd6d; font-weight:bold;">
      </p>
      <div id="slider-1"></div>

      <p>
         <label for="priceB">Price rangeB:</label>
         <input type="text" id="priceB" 
            style="border:0; color:#b9cd6d; font-weight:bold;">
      </p>
      <div id="slider-2"></div>
      <p>
         <label for="priceC">Price rangeC:</label>
         <input type="text" id="priceC" 
            style="border:0; color:#b9cd6d; font-weight:bold;">
      </p>
      <div id="slider-3"></div>
      <p>
         <label for="priceD">Price rangeD:</label>
         <input type="text" id="priceD" 
            style="border:0; color:#b9cd6d; font-weight:bold;">
      </p>
      <div id="slider-4"></div>
      <p>
         <label for="priceE">Price rangeE:</label>
         <input type="text" id="priceE" 
            style="border:0; color:#b9cd6d; font-weight:bold;">
      </p>
      <div id="slider-5"></div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is the problem? You are setting fields with a value...

Comment: Just curious, but given that all your values are 0, what is the point in doing calculations?

Comment: When I drag them I will see a value. I should calculate that value.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T9QNZ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value of the slider (or range in this case) using the API: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-values

Here is a fiddle that sums  the value of the top of the range on each slider:

http://jsfiddle.net/Epcm3/1/

This is the section of code that does the calculations:

```
function getValues() {
    var total = 0;
    $("div[id^='slider']").each(function () {
        var values = $(this).slider("option", "values");
        total += values[1];
    });
    $("#totals").text(total);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer jrussellaz. This is more than I wanted. Its perfect answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. The iteration example I provided may also help you with initializing the sliders, to shorten your code a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you then want to reference the value of any of the `range` inputs, you can just use `$('#id').val();` and assign that to some variable to perform operations on.

For example, with rangeC

```
var pricecVal = $('#priceC').val();
```

You could even update the value whenever the user changes the range with globals and this:

```
$("#priceC").bind("change", function() {
    pricecVal = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: no problem, you should use @jrussellaz 's method of iterating through the ids though